# Rotating picture error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, rotation

```
public Bitmap RotationPic(Bitmap tmpBitmap){
        int x = tmpBitmap.getWidth();
        int y = tmpBitmap.getHeight();
        if(x > y){

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.reset();
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(tmpBitmap,0,0, x, y,matrix, true);
        }
        return tmpBitmap;
    }
```

The sentence Bitmap.createBitmap(tmpBitmap,0,0, x, y,matrix, true);  has the error.

I read the network picture and the picture size is large, about 100k~300k.

How to solve this problem? Is there any other way to rotate picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this
but you need the path of pic to use this.
if you do not like resolution increase REQUIRED_SIZE value

```
public static Bitmap DecodeFileToBitmap (String path)
{
    try 
    {       
            File f = new File(path);

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=500;

            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale*=2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            Bitmap bitmap = bm;

            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try 
            {
                exif = new ExifInterface(path);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            if ((orientation == 3)) 
            {
                m.postRotate(180);
                m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float) bm.getHeight());
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            } 
            else if (orientation == 6) 
            {
                m.postRotate(90);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            }
            else if (orientation == 8) 
            {
                m.postRotate(270);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            }   

            return bitmap;
            }   

            catch(Exception ex) {}
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute Bitmap.createBitmap(tmpBitmap,0,0, x, y,matrix, true); to Bitmap.createBitmap(tmpBitmap,0,0, y, x,matrix, true); when you rotating image on 90 degree width=height and height=width